# How to combine slider with dataframe

Tags: python, streamlit

I have this:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from pandas import read_excel
from PIL import Image

st.set_page_config(page_title='TBI')
st.header('TBI sold result')
st.subheader('Info')

### --- LOAD DATAFRAME
excel_file = 'Directory'

sheet_name = 'Sheet2'

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file,
                   sheet_name=sheet_name,
                   usecols='H:O',
                   header=2)
df['Release_stock']=df['Release_stock'].fillna(0)


st.dataframe(df)

# --- STREAMLIT SELECTION

Date = df["Date"].dt.date.unique().tolist()



Model = st.sidebar.slider('Date:',
                        min_value= min(Date),
                        max_value= max(Date),
                        value=(min(Date),max(Date)))


mask = (df['Date'].dt.date.between(*Model))
number_of_result = df[mask].shape[0]
st.markdown(f'*Available Results: {number_of_result}*')
```

How to combine slider with my `DF` ?
I maked Date slider, but didnt work with my `DF`
I want the data in my table to be filtered at the same time when changing the date in slider

BTW date have 2022-06-01T00:00:00 format I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this minimal example.

#### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
from datetime import datetime


data = {
    'Date': ['2022-07-17', '2022-07-18', '2022-07-19', '2022-07-20', '2022-07-21', '2022-07-21'],
    'Sold': [5, 4, 8, 2, 9, 4]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

st.write('### Initial data')
st.dataframe(df)

Date = df["Date"].unique().tolist()

min_value = datetime.strptime(min(Date), '%Y-%m-%d')  # str to datetime
max_value = datetime.strptime(max(Date), '%Y-%m-%d')
value = (min_value, max_value)

Model = st.slider(
    'Date:',
    min_value=min_value,
    max_value=max_value,
    value=value)

selmin, selmax = Model
selmind = selmin.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  # datetime to str
selmaxd = selmax.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

dfres = df.loc[(df['Date'] >= selmind) & (df['Date'] <= selmaxd)]

st.write('### Data from selected date')
st.dataframe(dfres)
```

#### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try the DateSlider widget that allows selecting a date value within a set bounds using a slider

```python
import datetime as dt
import panel as pn

pn.extension()

min_df = df["Date"].min()

max_df = df["Date"].max()

date_slider = pn.widgets.DateSlider(name='Date Slider', start=min_df, end=max_df)

date_slider
```

More Information:

https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/widgets/DateSlider.html